# Boot to different partition after restore of operating system

Tags: centos, boot

Let's say I have a server with one RAID with 3 partitions:

- P1 - 20G OS / programs
- P2 - 190G Data
- P3 - 20G unused

If I ever need to roll back P1 to a previous state, and I've restored a past version of it to P3, what's the right way to update the system to now boot from P3 instead of P1.  Do I just mark the partition as active?  Do I need to edit some bootloader configuration?  Could I run into unexpected issues?

This pertains to CentOS 6, NOT using LVM.

EDIT July 29, 2015: to clarify, after performing this operation, I'd like P3 to be completely independent of P1 such that I could wipe out P1 and the system still function just fine.

EDIT2 July 29, 2015: for the sake of this question you can assume the system is using legacy BIOS and not UEFI if that matters.

Comment: Wait - after you restore (I assume using *dd* or similar tool) P3 to P1, you want to boot from P3? Not from P1?

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz After restoring a previous version of P1 from a bare metal backup software to P3, then I want to boot from P3 instead of P1.  The use cases are various non-emergency restore scenarios where an OS and/or software change was made that doesn't horribly break websites but that needs to be rolled back.  Let's say the restore takes a little while to run so rather than have downtime during that period, the only downtime would be the reboot.

Comment: How it happens depends first on the firmware, next *(if you have one)* your bootloader, and last on initramfs. You can configure any one of these to select the disk from which you boot in many different ways. It is easiest on an EFI system without a bootloader. And so you tell us - what currently selects your booting disk?

Comment: @mikeserv In this case there's only one disk (well multiple disks but a RAID so more like a single disk than not), but there are three partitions on it.  The OS is CentOS 6 and using grub.  I'm thinking that I'd need to mark P3 as active and edit grub's configuration, but I'm far from an expert in this arena - I'm hoping you or someone on here will be able to offer some guidance =). Thx

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` configuration file. This is the file which contains the configurations for [GRUB BootLoader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB).

Add a Menu entry in grub menu to boot from your OS reside in P3.

`/etc/grub.d/custom_entry` the menu entry will look something like this (Update with your disk number, partition number, linux image path, initrd path) (Follow the already existing menu entries in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file):

```
menuentry "My custom boot entry" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    linux /vmlinuz-3.11-custom
    initrd /initrd-plymouth.img
}
```

Once you have everything looking the way you want it to, you run:

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Reference - https://superuser.com/questions/781300/searching-for-grub-configuration-file-in-centos-7

Comment: Would I also want to do something like set the P3 partition to active to make the system completely independent of P1?

Comment: no need to mark the partition as active.

Comment: If P3 is a straight copy of P1, You'd also want to be careful of any explicit references to the device within your OS configuration.  E.g. in your /etc/fstab file, make sure that your /boot device is the right one.